# Stored procedure not returning records with PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Just started working on Stored Procedures, but not sure if I've completely miss understood them ... Here's a simple one I'm trying to get working, but it doesn't output anything:

```
CREATE procedure testprocedure (userID INT)
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT "Test procedure"
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID=userID;
END
```

Php:

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL testprocedure(:userid)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($row);
?>
```

Just outputs `array()`

But, if I use testprocedure(1) in Workbench, it returns a row

Any help appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

It was me being stupid ...

The user I was using to call the Stored Procedure didn't have the 'Execute' privilege ...

Simple as that Lol ...

On the bright side, I still have one third of my hair left

Comment: To keep the rest of your hair in the future jams: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858